# I am currently learning Javascript by grasshopper. And i am stucked in for loop

Tags: indexing

[Good im](https://i.stack.imgur.com/br4Qm.jpg)    **[enter image descrre](https://i.stack.imgur.com/br4Qm.jpg)**

Um can you see that example explanation?

"They said i-1 inside loop should start on the 2nd character" but i think it isn't am i right??? It should start first character
I confuse the first one  because 
Every time the loop start 1st character, not 2nd character.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [edit] your question accordingly. Put your code in the question, *never* as an image. Please also clarify what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

It's important to note the array is 0-based (in [JavaScript](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp)).

Let's use "jump" as the string in an array:

```
0 1 2 3
j u m p
```

The first loop will begin with "u" because i = 1.

```
egStr = "jump";
for (let i=1; i<egStr.length; i++) {
  let neighbor = i - 1; // i - 1 = 0
  console.log(egStr[i]); // returns 'u' first
  console.log(egStr[neighbor]); // returns 'j' first
}
```

The second loop will begin with "j" because i = 0.

```
egStr = "jump";
for (let i=0; i<egStr.length - 1; i++) {
  let neighbor = i + 1; // i + 1 = 1
  console.log(egStr[i]); // returns 'j' first
  console.log(egStr[neighbor]); // returns 'u' first
}
```